# How can I junit test the last block of this equal?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, junit4

How can I JUnit test the last block of this equal?

Any help would be much appreciated. This is the method in question:

```
@Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    //unreachable block
    ServiceOrderRelationship serviceOrderRelationship = (ServiceOrderRelationship) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.id, serviceOrderRelationship.id) &&
        Objects.equals(this.href, serviceOrderRelationship.href) &&
        Objects.equals(this.relationshipType, serviceOrderRelationship.relationshipType) &&
        Objects.equals(this.baseType, serviceOrderRelationship.baseType) &&
        Objects.equals(this.schemaLocation, serviceOrderRelationship.schemaLocation) &&
        Objects.equals(this.type, serviceOrderRelationship.type) &&
        Objects.equals(this.referredType, serviceOrderRelationship.referredType);
  }
```

This is what I've been doing but I can never reach the last block of code inside the equals method:

```
@Test
public void testEquals() throws Exception {

    assertFalse(serviceOrderRelationship.equals(null));
    assertTrue(serviceOrderRelationship.equals(serviceOrderRelationship));
    assertFalse(serviceOrderRelationship.equals(serviceOrderRelationship1));
}
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly ?, is your second assert failing ?, if so, unit test case will be terminated on first assertion error

Comment: The asserts are not failing but my test is not covering/reaching the block I mentioned

Comment: then it depends on how are you creating the objects to test, more code is needed, I think `if (this == o) { return true; }` is just being resolved at your 3rd assertion

Comment: Please add lines where you initialize `serviceOrderRelationship` and `serviceOrderRelationship1`

Comment: Are the serviceOrderRelationship and serviceOrderRelationship1 both referring to the same object?   Is the serviceOrderRelationship1 object null or not of the same class?  Either one would be the only way the last block would never be hit in your equals function.

Comment: Can you add serviceOrderRelationship and serviceOrderRelationship1 declaration?

Comment: Can’t you just step into the test and find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for your responses!

This is how I was able to reach the last block of the equals method. I had to initialize both objects di and di1 and set every variable to the same value, then test the equals condition switching back and forth one variable at a time to a different value. This is an example from another POJO:

```
    // Initialize objects
    di.setEdgeId("edgeId");
    di.setIdentityEndpoint("identityEndpoint");
    di.setUsername("username");

    di1.setEdgeId("edgeId");
    di1.setIdentityEndpoint("identityEndpoint");
    di1.setUsername("username");

    // Change value of var and test equal
    di1.setEdgeId("edgeIdm");
    assertFalse(di.equals(di1));
    di1.setEdgeId("edgeId");

    // same
    di1.setIdentityEndpoint("identityEndpointm");
    assertFalse(di.equals(di1));
    di1.setIdentityEndpoint("identityEndpoint");

    // Same
    di1.setUsername("usernamem");
    assertFalse(di.equals(di1));
    di1.setUsername("username");

    // Then at the end perform the other tests
    assertTrue(di.equals(di));
    assertTrue(di.equals(di1));
    assertFalse(di.equals(null));
    assertFalse(di.equals(42));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that one of the follow cases, in which the method would return prematurely.
If `serviceOrderRelationship` and `serviceOrderRelationship1` are references to the same object, the  true would be returned. Similarly, if they are not of the same type, false would be returned. If `serviceOrderRelationship1` is null, false would be returned.
If `serviceOrderRelationship` is null, then calling equals on it would throw a NullPointerException.